# Can't log into JetBrains Toolbox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, intellij

Running Ubuntu 18.04.3, though with KDE, I'm having a lot of trouble logging into the [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) (so that I can add my license and install non-free products).

When I go into the settings and click Log In, Chrome (my default browser) tries to open the link (`https://account.jetbrains.com/oauth2/signin?login_challenge={hash}`), which immediately redirects me to [a page](https://account.jetbrains.com/oauth2/error/challengeToken) saying:

> Oops! Something went wrong. Looks like you copied and pasted the link, it doesn’t work properly.
>   Please try again with your previous step on website/application or start over.

I found [a recent JetBrains issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-3684) that seems identical to my experience, but the only suggestions there were to reset my default browser to Edge or Safari for the login, depending on what OS I was on. I only had Firefox and Chrome available, and both were mentioned as browsers people had had this issue with, but I tried opening the initial URL in both anyway to the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My KDE settings for default browser/how to open http(s) URLs looked like this:

[image: KDE Default Application Web Browser settings, showing three options for how to open http and https URLs: in an application based on the contents of the URL(selected), in the following application (followed by a greyed out dropdown with Google Chrome visible), with the following command (followed by a greyed out textbox currently reading 'google-chrome')]

Despite the fact the linked issue suggested a fix might be to do with allowing the toolbox to open `jetbrains://` URLs, switching to having links directly opened in Chrome (with the second option) allowed Chrome to successfully open the Log in link and ask for permissions, allowing me to log in.